# How can I use SQL Substring to extract characters from this filename?

Tags: sql, substring, extract, charindex

I'm attempting to use the SUBSTRING function to extract a name out of a filename.

An example filename would be: "73186_RHIMagnesita_PHI_StopLoss_TruncSSN_NonRedact_Inc_to_Apr2022_Paid_to_Apr2022_EDIT"
I'm attempting to extract the "RHIMagnesita" from this filename.

The substring I used was:

```
SUBSTRING(DFH.FileName, CHARINDEX('_', DFH.FileName) + 1, CHARINDEX('_PHI', DFH.FileName) - 1)
```

The results it gave were: "RHIMagnesita_PHI_S"

How do I extract only "RHIMagnesita" using the Substring function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter in SUBSTRING is length not position, so you would need to substract the length of the beginning string.

```
SUBSTRING(DFH.FileName, CHARINDEX('_', DFH.FileName) + 1, CHARINDEX('_PHI', DFH.FileName) - CHARINDEX('_', DFH.FileName))
```

You might need to add or substract 1, but that's the idea.

Comment: It wont let me vote up.

Comment: You should be able to accept it as the answer since you're a new user.

Answer (score 0):

You were close.  You need to use `CHARINDEX` to also find the position of the second underscore.

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(FileName,
                 CHARINDEX('_', FileName) + 1,
                 CHARINDEX('_', FileName, CHARINDEX('_', FileName) + 1) -
                     CHARINDEX('_', FileName) - 1) AS FilePart
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using STRING_SPLIT and FETCH, rather than SUBSTRING We split the string and only return the second row

```
SELECT
   value
FROM   STRING_SPLIT('73186_RHIMagnesita_PHI_StopLoss_TruncSSN_NonRedact_Inc_to_Apr2022_Paid_to_Apr2022_EDIT','_')
ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
OFFSET 1 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Note: On Azure Sql Server STRING_SPLIT has an ordinal parameter, so you could write this

```
SELECT
value
FROM
STRING_SPLIT('73186_RHIMagnesita_PHI_StopLoss_TruncSSN_NonRedact_Inc_to_Apr2022_Paid_to_Apr2022_EDIT','_', 1)
WHERE ordinal = 2
```